# Mysql Set Variable ve Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I have a question about mysql stored procedure and variables;

Table Name : es_adwords
Fields : id  # image_source # image_link # computer_id # is_all_pc # image_state # banner_size

I want to create stored procedure that should search  computer_id = {pc_number} and image_state = 0.

If not, stored procedure should return to be equal to is_all_pc = 1.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetAdwordsBanner` $$
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAdwordsBanner`(IN compid INT)
BEGIN
SET @result_id := 0;

SELECT @result_id := id FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND computer_id = compid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;

IF (@result_id != 0) THEN
    SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND computer_id = compid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
ELSE
    SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND is_all_pc = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sincerely Yours...

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where did you get stuck? What errors do you get if any?

Comment: Does not work the way I want

Comment: What do you expect? And what do you get instead?

Comment: On my table, If computer_id = {compid (pass through paramater)} and image_state = 1, stored procedure should "SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND computer_id = compid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;" otherwise stored procedure should return  "SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND is_all_pc = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic has a problem. I would rewrite this to:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAdwordsBanner`(IN compid INT)
BEGIN
-- use a local variable instead of a user variable
DECLARE result_count INT;
-- count how many rows are matching
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_id FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND computer_id = compid;

-- if there are matches    
IF result_count > 0 THEN
    -- return the first matching row
    SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND computer_id = compid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
ELSE
    -- return the default one
    SELECT image_source,image_link,banner_size FROM es_adwords WHERE image_state = 1 AND is_all_pc = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This should work.